# what is the output of conditional operator with unary operator

Tags: c++, boolean, conditional-operator, assignment-operator, integer-promotion

I have the following code where behavior is not clear to me. Can some one please help how conditional operator evaluate the following code and output ans as 1

#include

```
int main() {

bool delayMessages=0;
bool Delay = false;
delayMessages += Delay ? 1 : -1;
std::cout << "Hello world!"<<delayMessages;

return 0;
} 

Ans: Hello world!1
```

Can soemone please help how thsi code is evaluated "delayMessages += Delay ? 1 : -1;"

Comment: `delayMessages` should be an integer type, not a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression on the right hand side is evaluated like an if-statement.

```cpp
if (Delay == true)
   return 1;
else
   return -1;
```

The result is then used for the `+=` assignment.

In the
[C++20 draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) standard that's

> 7.6.19 (6) (Assignment and compound assignment operators)
>
> The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1 op E2` except that E1 is
> evaluated only once. [...]

Since `Delay == false`, the return value of the ternary operator is `-1`. The fact that you're operating on a `bool`ean instead of an `int` can make it look like you got the `+1` back.

Note that you get a compiler warning [C4804](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4804?view=msvc-170):

> warning C4804: '+=': unsafe use of type 'bool' in operation

Is it undefined behavior? No.

> 7.6.19 (6) (Assignment and compound assignment operators)
>
> [...]  For += and
> -=, E1 shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly cv-qualified completely-defined object
> type. In all other cases, E1 shall have arithmetic type.

and

> 7.3.8 (2) (Integral conversions)
>
> If the destination type is bool, see 7.3.14.

which says

> 7.3.14 (1) (Boolean conversions)
>
> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type can be converted to a
> prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
> any other value is converted to true.

So the -1 is converted to `true` and `true` prints as 1.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ 17 Standard (7.6 Integral promotions)

> 6 A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int,
> with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

and (7.14 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
> to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
> value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
> to false; any other value is converted to true. For
> direct-initialization (11.6), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
> converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

and at last (8.7 Additive operators)

> 1 The additive operators + and - group left-to-right. The usual
> arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or
> enumeration type.

This expression statement

```
delayMessages += Delay ? 1 : -1;
```

can be rewritten like

```
delayMessages = delayMessages + ( Delay ? 1 : -1 );
```

The result of the expression with the conditional operator is `-1` because the first sub-expression (`Delay`) evaluates to `false`.

So in fact you have

```
delayMessages = delayMessages + -1;
```

The variable `delayMessage` declared like

```
bool delayMessages=0;
```

has the value `false` according to the quotes from the section 7.14.

In the expression with binary plus operator + it is converted to the integer 0 according to the quotes (7.6 Integral promotions) and 8.7 Additive operators and you have

```
delayMessages = 0 + -1;
```

or

```
delayMessages = -1;
```

Again according to the quote 7.14 Boolean conversions the result value of the variable `delayMessage` will be `true`.

The operator << outputs a boolean value true as 1 in this statement

```
std::cout << "Hello world!"<<delayMessages;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Delay ? 1 : -1
```

evaluates to `-1` because `Delay` is false. Converting `-1` to `bool` yields `true` because only `0` is converted to `false`. Then printing the `true` prints `1`. The result is `true` no matter if `Delay` is `true` or `false` and `1` is printed in both cases.

Use `true` / `false` for booleans and use an integer type for integers. Perhaps this is what you actually wanted to do:

```
int delayMessages=0;
bool Delay = false;
delayMessages += Delay ? 1 : -1;
std::cout << "Hello world!"<<delayMessages;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delayMessages += Delay ? 1 : -1;
```

This basically means if `Delay` is true, then `delayMessages += 1` (which is 1), else `delayMessages += -1` (which is also 1).